# Browsers that support HTML5; will they stop supporting tags & attributes which are not supported by HTML5?

Tags: html

For tag `<tr>`; none of the attributes(align, bgcolor, char, charoff, valign) are supported in HTML5.

Will any browser ever actually stop supporting it?Will the attributes stop making sense to browser?

Comment: Maybe because you've got an alternative (better) way to do that ... it's CSS.

Comment: @codehorse :- For now, & probably few more years, 'Not supported in HTML5' is just a message. (In legacy code) Ignoring it is harmless.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no such things as being “supported by HTML5”. HTML5 is a draft specification, and specifications do not “support” things, though they may require conforming implementations to support (implement) things.

Attributes like `align`, `bgcolor`, `char`, `charoff`, and `valign` are described in HTML5 CR and it requires implementations to support them. Thus, assuming that HTML5 CR will be approved as a specification, a conforming brower *will* keep supporting them. This is by definition: if it stops supporting them, it is not conforming.

Quite apart from this, HTML5 CR declares those attributes entirely obsolete and defines that conforming *documents* must not use them. But this is just a requirement on documents and authors, and violating the requirement has no implications as such.

On the other hand, the `char` and `charoff` attributes and the attribute specification `align=char` are not supported by browsers. This has nothing to do with their being declared obsolete in HTML. It's just so that they, or their CSS counterparts, have not been implemented in browsers.